# How channel state information is calculated from Sounding Packet

Tags: wifi

What I understand is for Explicit Transmit Beamforming scenario in 802.11n, the Transmitter sends an NDP packet(aka HT Sounding) which consist of OFDM training symbols in packet preamble (HT-LTF) which are randomly generated +/-1 for each subcarrier frequency(say 56).

I do not have much understanding on this, but if anyone can help me to understand or provide any solid link on how these training symbols are calculated at the receiver end to evaluate CSI(channel state information) will be helpful.